# Why is DateTime not unboxed properly?

Tags: c#, datetime

I am doing a simple casting of object to DateTime. The object is also a DateTime. However the unboxed value is not the same as object.

I even tried `System.Convert.ToDateTime(value)` but that made no difference.

What is happening here that I am missing.

```
private object Convert(object value, DateTimeConversionTypes dateTimeConversionTypes)
{
    switch (dateTimeConversionTypes)
    {
        case DateTimeConversionTypes.ToLocal:
        {
            if (!(value is DateTimeOffset)) return null;
            var dtValue = (DateTimeOffset)value;
            if (dtValue == DateTimeOffset.MinValue) return null;
            var returnValue = dtValue.ToLocalTime().DateTime;
            returnValue = DateTime.SpecifyKind(returnValue, DateTimeKind.Local);
            return returnValue;
        }
        case DateTimeConversionTypes.ToUtc:
        {
            if (!(value is DateTime)) return null;
            var dtValue = (DateTime)value;
            if (dtValue == DateTime.MinValue) return null;
            var returnValue = dtValue.ToUniversalTime();
            returnValue = DateTime.SpecifyKind(returnValue, DateTimeKind.Utc);
            return new DateTimeOffset(returnValue);
        }
        default:
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(dateTimeConversionTypes), dateTimeConversionTypes, null);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Should you use DateTimeOffset in both cases?

Comment: @mayu: I can't , this is a WPF converter converting between a ViewModel `DateTimeOffset` and UI control `DateTime`.

Comment: I don't what it is, but it's strange that dtValue has a +00:00 offset and value doesn't have the offset string. In your debug window `dtValue` is a `DateTimeOffset`. Did you do any debug dragging?

Comment: 1) Are you debugging in Release mode by any chance? 2) If you step through to the next statement, does it actually reach the return null?

Comment: @JeffE: 1) No, breakpoints do not hit in release mode and 2) No.

Comment: The code in the screenshot is not the same as the code in the snippet.  You do have two dtValue variables in the code, the debugger displays the other one.

Comment: @HansPassant: The pic is from second case of switch.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess I have found the answer and need community to confirm.

This is due to same variable names used in switch cases. Even though there are brackets and have solid scopes, still somehow (don't know why) it is treating the two varaiables as same. When I changed the variable names to unique ones, it started doing the desired behaviour.

Comment: Prove this assertion. It doesn't sound right. Can you please show two lots of code - one that has the issue and one that doesn't - so that we can see it working the way you describe. We should be able to copy, paste & run it.

Comment: @Enigmativity: How do you explain `dtValue` to have `Offset` even though its `DateTime`.

Comment: I'm interested in seeing code that proves that this is the case. You say "still somehow (don't know why)" - until you can show why then this isn't an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how, but I'm guessing that dtValue was created as 'DateTimeOffset' (this is why its text representation has +00:00).